# How to group by multiple variabes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2, the `aes()` command allows to break down the data set by setting `group =`, `color =` etc. Is there a way to group by multiple variables, similar to the way that dplyr allows to set multiple `group_by` commands?

For example, I would like to plot densities for the "Titanic" data set broken down by the variables `"Female"` and `"Survived"` with regard to the age. Both `"Female"` and `"Survived"` are dummy variables, so I would like to end up with four densities.

Intuitively, I would pass `c("Female", "Survived")` to the `group` attribute inside `aes()`, as in the code below. What would be the correct way to do this?

```
library("tidyverse")

titanic <- read_csv("https://stanford.io/2O9RUCF",
                    col_types = cols(
                      Survived = col_logical(),
                      Pclass = col_integer(),
                      Name = col_character(),
                      Sex = col_character(),
                      Age = col_double(),
                      `Siblings/Spouses Aboard` = col_integer(),
                      `Parents/Children Aboard` = col_integer(),
                      Fare = col_double()
                    ))

titanic <- titanic %>% 
  mutate(Female = (Sex == "Female")) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Sex, -Name)


titanic %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_density(aes(Age, color = c(Female, Survived)))
```

Comment: `color=interaction(Female, Survived)`. `interaction` creates a new factor variable from the individual variables. You could also do `colour=paste(Female, Survived, sep="-")`.

Comment: You can also try something like this geom_density(aes(Age, color=Female, fill=Survived), alpha=0.5)

Comment: For some reason both `interaction(Female, Survived)` and `paste(Female, Survived, sep="-")` only give me two combinations.

Comment: How many combinations are in the data frame `titanic`?

Comment: @dufei change your ```mutate``` call to ```mutate(Female = (Sex == "female"))```, with a lower case "f", then you'll get four combinations from ```interaction```

Comment: There must be a problem with my recoding of `Sex`. Before, all combinations are present; but not after the recoding. Before recoding, `interaction(Female, Survived)` yields four different densities.

Comment: @Greg: Just saw that too, thanks! I'll try to delete this question - it all comes down to my ignorance, after all!